# How can I find the second most common number in an array?

Tags: python, scipy

I have tried using `scipy.stats` mode to find the most common value. My matrix contains a lot of zeros, though, and so this is always the mode.

For example, if my matrix looks like the following:

```
array = np.array([[0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0],
             [5, 2, 1, 2, 6, 7],
             [0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0]])
```

I'd like to have the value of `2` returned.

Comment: So what happened when you used `scipy.stats`?also this is not a valid list or python array!!

Comment: If you don't want to include 0, filter it out of the data and then get the stats of the result.

Comment: `{...}` is the notation for a `set`, not a `list`, which uses the notation `[...]` (there is no such thing as an `array` in Python). A `set` will only ever have each element once, so there won't be such a thing as the "second most common number" in it. Also, you're missing commas between the elements in your set, so what you've written isn't even valid Python.

Comment: Probably the OP is talking about a `numpy` array, as they're using `scipy.stats`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in some comments, you probably are speaking of numpy arrays.

In this case, it is rather simple to mask the value you want to avoid:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode

array = np.array([[0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0],
                 [5, 2, 1, 2, 6, 7],
                 [0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0]])
flat_non_zero = array[np.nonzero(array)]
mode(flat_non_zero)
```

Which returns `(array([2]), array([ 4.]))` meaning the value appearing the most is 2, and it appears 4 times (see the [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.mode.html) for more info). So if you want to only get 2, you just need to get the first index of the return value of the mode : `mode(flat_non_zero)[0][0]`

EDIT: if you want to filter another specific value x from array instead of zero, you can use `array[array != x]`

Answer (score 10):

Try `collections.Counter`:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

a = np.array(
  [[0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0],
   [5, 2, 1, 2, 6, 7],
   [0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0]]
)

ctr = Counter(a.ravel())
second_most_common_value, its_frequency = ctr.most_common(2)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
original_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]  #original list
noDuplicates = list(set(t))                  #creates a list of all the unique numbers of the original list

most_common = [noDuplicates[0], original_list.count(noDuplicates[0])]  #initializes most_most common to 
                                                                       #the first value and count so we have something to start with


for number in noDuplicates:         #loops through the unique numbers
    if number != 0:                 #makes sure that we do not check 0
        count = original_list.count(number)     #checks how many times that unique number appears in the original list
        if count > most_common[1]   #if the count is greater than the most_common count
            most_common = [number, count] #resets most_common to the current number and count


print(str(most_common[0]) + " is listed " + str(most_common[1]) + "times!")
```

This loops through your list and finds the most used number and prints it with the number of occurrences in your original list.